# WPF ListBox Layout (dynamic column width considering all rows at once)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, columndefinition

Is there a way to make sure that the `Width="auto"` property considers the `Width` of all elements in a list instead of calculating it individually for every row in the list?

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I tried this, but as the length of the `Name` is different for each column, the `Width` of the `Name` column of every row is different. Thus the second column starts at a different x position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SharedSizeGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the `ColumnDefinition` like this:

```
<ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
```

Also have a look at this: [Grid Size Sharing in WPF](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2007/08/27/grid-size-sharing-in-wpf/).